# Mirror selection but maintain current selection

Tags: mirror

I'm new to blender (have previously tried older versions) and I'm loving 2.8, I'm having some difficulty with something I feel is probably user error but I have been trying to select some vertices on one side of my model and have my selection mirrored to the other side while keeping the current selection (like add mirror to current selection).

Is there an easy way for me to do this without having to create modifiers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best solution, but I have found that it works. Start by going into Edit Mode, make sure you've opened the Object Data tab of the Properties Panel (1), then create a vertex group for the initial selection of vertices. Create the new group by pressing the + sign to the right (2), and include the selected vertices by clicking the "Assign" button (3).

[image]

Next, while still in Edit Mode, locate the "Select" Menu at the top left of the 3D-View, and open it to choose the "Mirror Selection" option at the bottom of that menu.

[image]

Finally, go back to the Vertex Group you created and press the "Select" button to get back your original selection.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks, strange that there's no way to do this with regular mirror selection by holding alt or something

Comment: Silly me. When I first answered, I didn't yet know that when you first select the Mirror Selection option, the dialog box that pops up at the bottom of the screen has a checkbox in it called "Extend." If it is checked, it will keep your existing selection after you mirror it. So you can skip the vertex group step. Hurray!